# is python's "Exception Ignored" in module threading avoidable?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I have an application with many threads running on the terminal, all of which loop around checking an `Event` that signals them for shutdown when set. using [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) I set the `Event` for them, and wait for all threads to terminate via `.join`, and then shutdown the main. This works as intended when I terminate the application by hitting ctrl-c, except that I get:

```
Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.8/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1388, in _shutdown
    lock.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

I do not get any details as part of this error message, other than those contained in the snippet above.

I have done some reading on similar aspects, but couldn't figure out whether this indicates a loophole in my shutdown sequence, or whether this is *unavoidable* when there are multiple threads running when the program is terminated from the outside. Can you explain?

And otherwise, in case this situation is not clean/normal for a python application using the `threading` module, what are the design choices for correctly avoiding this situation in a python application heavily using `threading.Thread` for multiple threads?

Comment: Threads generally do not receive signals, including ``KeyboardInterrupt``. Can you provide an [mcve] for your shutdown mechanism and the ignored exception?

Comment: What might you mean by the word _generally_ there?

Comment: There are certain ways to raise a ``KeyboardInterrupt`` in a thread, and do similar things. These involve directly accessing interpreter internals – meaning it is technically possible, but *usually* does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. Looking at the threading.py file, it seems that the _shutdown() function is the main thread waiting for other threads to stop before the main thread can be released. I think if this problem doesn't bother you too much, just use 'crtl+c' to end the process